# What is the MySQL session variable equivalent to Sybase ASE's APPLICATIONNAME?

Tags: mysql, session, variables, connection

APPLICATIONNAME in Sybase is used in information schema queries (current connections, slow queries, etc.), so the results contian not just a thread/process id, but a more human readable description of the application responsible for the given query.

Is there an equivalent to it in mysql? My google fu failed me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an SQL email list (sq-l at list.prog.hu) I got the answer that no, this is not supported on MySQL, but a relatively common workaround is to prefix each SQL statement with a descriptive comment identifying the issuing application.

E.g.:

```
/* cms_blog_module */ select * from blog_posts where id = ....
```

And this way, wherever a query is present, its source is present as well